# Get access to GATT server on a bluetooth device discovered using experimental BLE scanning in Chrome

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, web-bluetooth

I am working on a POC where I use the experimental BLE scan interface to discover multiple Bluetooth devices, and connect to their GATT services from a web application.

Requesting a single device using `navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice` yields a device where I can connect to the GATT server.

When when I try to discover devices using `requestLEScan`, the devices I receive does not allow me to connect to the GATT server.

```
  const [ devices, dispatch ] = useReducer(reducer, {});
  const scanClick = () => {
    navigator.bluetooth.requestLEScan({
      acceptAllAdvertisements: true,
    }).then((scan) => {
      setTimeout(() => scan.stop(), 10000);
    });
    navigator.bluetooth.addEventListener('advertisementreceived', (event) => {
      console.log("DEVICE DETECTED", event);
      parseBluetoothDevice(event.device).then(x => x && dispatch(x));
    });
  }

const parseBluetoothDevice = async (device) => {
  // Should return a representation with the device information I want to display
  await device.gatt.connect();
  ...
}
```

The call to `device.gatt.connect()` throws an error:

> GATT operation not authorized

How do I get authorized to access the GATT server on the detected device?

Is my problem that I need to call `permissions.request()`, which is not yet implemented for Bluetooth? ([Bluetooth implementation status](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/blob/gh-pages/implementation-status.md))

I have tried instead of setting `acceptAllAdvertisement`, to pass `filters` with a service UUID that I know my devices support - and that I want to query, but then I don't see any scan results.

I am running Chrome 83.0.4103.97  on MacOS with "experimental web features" enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The `requestLEScan()` API only grants permission to start a scan and see advertisement packets from nearby devices, but it does not grant permission to connect to these devices. To do this, you would need to use `requestDevice()` and add the services that you're interested in using to the filter or to `optionalServices`.

In Chrome, the prompt displayed when `requestDevice()` requires the user to select the Bluetooth device that they want to allow the site to connect to, whereas the prompt displayed for `requestLEScan()` only asks if the user wants to allow the site to scan for nearby Bluetooth devices. This is why you aren't able to connect to these devices.

Comment: Thanks, but if I have first scanned for devices, and found the ones that are interesting to talk to, how can I specifically request that device? `requestDevice({ deviceId: event.device.id })` does not work? In my concrete application, I will need to connect to multiple devices, which I believe I can detect based on manufacturer information.

Comment: The [RequestDeviceOptions](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#dictdef-requestdeviceoptions) doesn't contain a way to specify the device ID. If you want to specifically filter the device, you can add the `name` and `services` fields, as well as any service and manufacturer data. If you want to access any additional services that are not in the advertisement packet, you need to add that to `optionalServices` to get permission for those. Unfortunately, there isn't an easy way to grant permission for multiple devices at once at the moment.

Comment: It makes sense that the API should enable Scan -> Connect eventually.  However, `requestLEScan` is only a prototype now and development is paused.  Eventually it does make sense to enable a path for `device.gatt.connect()` to work, but it will require a specification design for how user permission will be requested and implementation.